# How to make QToolBar to fit as much actions as possible

Tags: qt, user-interface, qtoolbar

I have 2 `QToolBar` objects placed horizontaly one after another. The first one contains essential actions, the other - optional. I'd like the first toolbar to fit as much actions as possible, but can't get it - if the second bar contains too much, the first one show some actions and hides the others after an extension button. I tried to setup `sizePolicy` property, but it doesn't help. At the same time it is possible to setup `minWidth` for the first bar so that all the actions will be visible, but I think it is an ugly solution. Any ideas, please?